# Can I use regex to specify index of an array that I want to compare to a value?

Tags: regex, perl

Here's a small example of what I'm trying to do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$nums = "a,b,c,1,2,3";
@arr = split(",", $nums);

# If the contents of indexes 3 through 5 all match the correct syntax (any integer), print the message
if($arr[/^[3-5]{1}/] =~ /^[0-9]+/ ) {
     print "Those elements in this array are all numbers";
}else{
     print "\nsome of those elements are not numbers"
}
```

will this work to test if elements 3 to 5 are all integers?

Comment: What the heck is this line supposed to mean: `if($arr[/^[3-5]{1}/] =~ /^[0-9]+/ ) {` You are trying to take an array slice from `@arr`, by executing a pattern match on `$_` (undefined at this point) matching beginning of line `^`  followed by one number 3-5, and you want to match this against beginning of line, and numbers. This is not valid Perl code, and it is not clear what you intend to do.

Answer (score 4):

That won't work. `/^[3-5]{1}/` will return `0` or `1` depending on the value of `$_`, so it would only check `$arr[0]` or `$arr[1]`.

You could use

```perl
all { arr[$_] =~ /^[0-9]+\z/ } 3..5
```

or

```perl
all { /^[0-9]+\z/ } @arr[3..5]
```

`all` is provided by List::Util. This could be adapted to use `grep` instead.

```perl
!grep { arr[$_] !~ /^[0-9]+\z/ } 3..5
```

or

```perl
!grep { !/^[0-9]+\z/ } @arr[3..5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array elements of interest and drop flag on first not number, then output result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $nums = 'a,b,c,1,2,3';
my @arr  = split ',', $nums;
my $flag = 1;                   # Lets assume that all elements are numbers

for my $element ( @arr[3..5] ) {
    $flag = 0 && last if $element !~ /^\d+/;
}

say $flag ? "all elements are numbers" :"not all elements are numbers";
```